# Remove excess white space above figure

Tags: graphics, floats

I have a figure defined by the following code:

```
    \begin{figure}[H]    
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.48\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[height=0.25\textheight]{r3.1per4.png} 
    \caption{Ciclo de Período 4, $r = 3.1$ e iterações de $100$ a $150$.} 
    \label{fig:output of knock R1_N_1} 
  \end{subfigure}% 
  \hspace{\fill} 
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.48\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[height=0.25\textheight]{r3.8310per6.png} 
    \caption{Ciclo de Período 6, $r = 3.831$ e iterações de $100$ a $150$.} 
    \label{fig:output of knock R1_N_4} 
  \end{subfigure}%

  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.48\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[height=0.25\textheight]{r3.507peri8.png} 
    \caption{Ciclo de Período 8, $r = 3.507$ e iterações de $100$ a $150$.} 
    \label{fig:output of knock R1_N_r_2} 
  \end{subfigure} 
  \hspace{\fill}
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.48\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[height=0.25\textheight]{r3.74per10.png} 
    \caption{Ciclo de Período 10, $r = 3.74$ e iterações de $100$ a $150$.} 
    \label{fig:output of knock R1_N_r_6} 
  \end{subfigure} 

  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.48\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[height=0.25\textheight]{r3.559per16.png} 
    \caption{Ciclo de Período 16, $r = 3.559$ e iterações de $100$ a $150$.} 
    \label{fig:output of knock R1_N_8} 
  \end{subfigure}
  \hspace{\fill}
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.48\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[height=0.25\textheight]{r3.5830per24.png} 
    \caption{Ciclo de Período 24, $r = 3.583$ e iterações de $100$ a $150$.} 
    \label{fig:output of knock R1_C_2} 
  \end{subfigure} 

   \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.48\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[height=0.25\textheight]{r3.538per32.png} 
    \caption{Ciclo de Período 32, $r = 3.568$ e iterações de $100$ a $150$.} 
    \label{fig:output of knock R1_C_5} 
  \end{subfigure}
  \hspace{\fill}
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.48\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[height=0.25\textheight]{r3.634per36.png} 
    \caption{Ciclo de Período 36, $r = 3.634$ e iterações de $100$ a $150$.} 
    \label{fig:output of knock R1_C_7} 
  \end{subfigure} 

\caption{Knockdown of proposed interactions in region R1}
\label{fig:output of knock R1} 
\end{figure}
```

The resulting document had too much space above and is cut at the bottom of the page, as you can see bellow.

[image: Image produced.]

How can I remove the excess space above, and make it not clip the page bellow?

Comment: `\vspace*{-1cm}` after `\begin{figure}` ? (or however much space you need)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I tried it before and after `\begin{figure}` and both seem to work in the MWE that I used. Is `\vspace*` (starred version) maybe a more robust approach?

Comment: Note that 0.25 × 4 = 1. There are not any room for captions. The right solution is reduce the image size, not move the float, that anyway will be out of margins.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on David's excellent comment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % demo: placeholder images
\usepackage{float} % [H]
\usepackage{subcaption} % subfigure
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\blindtext

% https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/How_to_Write_a_Thesis_in_LaTeX_(Part_3)%3A_Figures%2C_Subfigures_and_Tables
\begin{figure}[H]
\vspace{-15mm} % <-- Go crazy here!
     \centering
     \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
         \centering
         \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{graph1}
         \caption{$y=x$}
         \label{fig:y equals x}
     \end{subfigure}
     \hfill
     \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
         \centering
         \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{graph2}
         \caption{$y=3sinx$}
         \label{fig:three sin x}
     \end{subfigure}
     \hfill
     \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
         \centering
         \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{graph3}
         \caption{$y=5/x$}
         \label{fig:five over x}
     \end{subfigure}
        \caption{Three simple graphs}
        \label{fig:three graphs}
\end{figure}

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

Comment: I appreciate the answer, but it doesn't seem to be doing anything.

Comment: @Rodrigo You can see that the picture is overlapping with the text. Just try some extreme values for `\vspace{-15mm}`, such as `30mm` or `-30mm`.

Comment: Maybe experiment with placing `\vspace{-15mm}` BEFORE `\begin{figure}[H]`.

Comment: You can also use `\usepackage{showpage}` to see the page borders etc. This is often helpful in debugging.

Comment: The screenshot show why `\vspace` should not be used.  The problem seems that the image sizes are too big to  fit the float in the text area and then the best solution could be reduce the image sizes, not probably move them out of the top margin (without a MWE is hard to say).

Comment: I even tried with `\vspace{-10cm}`, @Manuel.  Thanks a bunch, though!

Comment: @Rodrigo Then maybe trying to reduce the size of each subfigure by, for example, 25 percent. And change height=0.25\textheight to height=0.20\textheight.

Comment: As Fran already mentioned, your whole figure is probably too large for a single page at the moment.